# Position not rendering with specific div in css

Tags: html, css

I have an issue rendering the position of a specific element with different screen resolutions.

Below is my code:

```css
li.Dashboard > ul
{ 
  display:none; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:15.5%;  
  top:138px; 
  z-index:9; 
  vertical-align:top !important;
}

li.Dashboard li .subnav 
{  
  position:relative; 
  margin: 0px; 
  margin-top: 10px; 
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<LI class="Dashboard active" id=Dashboard jQuery1428391652078="2">
  <A id=hlDashboard href="PermanentReqFollowUp.aspx?2=7">
    <SPAN></SPAN>
    <SMALL></SMALL>
  </A>
  <UL>
    <LI jQuery1428391652078="4">
      <DIV class="subnav_bg subnav">
        <UL class=subnav_ul>
          <LI jQuery1428391652078="6">
            <A class="dxeHyperlink PermanentReqFollowUp" id=hlTechnipEmpFollowUp href="PermanentReqFollowUp.aspx?2=9">Monitoring of Permanent Employees Requests</A>
          </LI>
          <LI jQuery1428391652078="8">
            <A class="dxeHyperlink IntrimReqFollowUp" id=hlInterimEmpFollowUp href="InterimReqFollowUp.aspx?2=10">Monitoring of Interim Employees Requests</A>
          </LI>
        </UL>
      </DIV>
    </LI>
  </UL>
</LI>
```

The position of `Dashboard` is not rendering well inside `.subnav`.
It positioning out of `Dashboard` when I try in all screen resolutions.

**Problem occurs only in IE but works fine in Chrome.**

Comment: Can you add your code in the form of code snippet so that others will get a better idea of it.

Comment: Do you have double quotes in your code for the ul class `subnav_ul` - and all of the other IDs and classes that don't appear to have quotes in them. You need to add these.

Comment: @Lee you don't need the quotes (at least not in HTML5) for single attributes.

Comment: Well let's assume he's not using HTML5, as it's not specified directly, and there's a mixture of quotes and non-quotes... and also that HTML5 is still considered experimental.

Comment: @Lee HTML5 was finalized and accepted as the new specification months ago (2014, Oct. 28th). [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)

Comment: Lol, W3 schools and Wiki say we should use quotes anyway (seems to be the more common opinion).

Comment: i checked with my source code . I found quotes

Comment: @Arunraj but the quotes don't show here in your message. What other differences are there between your real source and the message?

Comment: this code i copied from  browser view source